# AngularJs indexOf de Object

Tags: array, angularjs, indexof

Toda vez que seleciono um bundle, adiciono em um array, exemplo:

Items são alguns dados que pego, passei só alguns para teste

```
var items = [755, 20, "E", 274] 

$scope.selectBundle = function(){

    var info = {
        cod: items[3],
        bundle: items[0],
        espessura: items[1],
        classificacao: items[2]
    };
    // Passa as informações para o cart
    $rootScope.selectedBundle.push(info);

    // Fecha o modal
    $modalInstance.close();
}
```

Sempre que clico para abrir um novo modal, "items" mudam de valores e vai adicionando no scope de selecionados.

O que eu quero e não estou conseguindo é se no próximo modal que eu for abrir, verificar se já existe as informações do bundle no array para deixar o botão de selecionar disativado

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/hqypngej/1/
Fiz semelhante ao meu código para mostrar como exemplo.

Algumas partes do meu arquivo JS está assim no momento:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $http){

    $rootScope.cod_mercad = null;

    $rootScope.selectedBundle = [];
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, $modal){

    $scope.open = function (bundle, espessura, classificacao, codigo) {

        $scope.items = [bundle, espessura, classificacao, codigo];

        // console.log($scope.items);
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'rotas/modal', // Endereço da view modal
            windowClass: 'full',
            size: 'lg',
            controller: 'modalController',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// Controller que define todo o modal
app.controller('modalController', function($scope, $http,$modalInstance, $rootScope, items){

    // Busca as informações do bundle passando os dados
    $http.post('/ajax/bundle', {'items':items}).success(function(data){

        $scope.dados = data['dados'];
        $scope.nchapas = data['chapas'];
        $scope.imagens = data['imagens'];

        // Define o tamanho da div que mostra as imagens secundarias
        // (Total de imagens + imagem principal) * tamanho de cada bloco somando com margin + padding do conteudo
        var width = $scope.imagens.length * 215 + 30;
        $('#imagem-secundaria').css('width',width);
    });

    // Seleção de bundle
    $scope.selectBundle = function() {

        var info = {
            cod: items[3],
            bundle: items[0],
            espessura: items[1],
            classificacao: items[2]
        };
        // Passa as informações para o cart
        $rootScope.selectedBundle.push(info);

        // Fecha o modal
        $modalInstance.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Não conheço o Angular mto bem, é isto que pretende? http://jsfiddle.net/hqypngej/

Comment: Então, eu tento fazer deste jeito, mas o repetido sempre retorna true na aplicação.

Comment: Atualizei o fiddle, agora ele está com o mesmo erro que o meu sistema. http://jsfiddle.net/hqypngej/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema de uma maneira tão simples.

```
// Percorre todos os itens selecionados
angular.forEach($rootScope.selectedBundle,function(value, key){
    // Informa ao botão quais bundles são verdadeiros
    $rootScope.selectBundleButton[value] = true;
});
```

E no modal deixo o seguinte

```
<a href="#" ng-show="!selectBundleButton[items]" ng-click="selectBundle()"> Selecionar bundle </a>
```